# How to view movements between accounts inside a transaction?

Tags: transaction-instructions

Is there a technical way to see the movements between accounts that are generated during a transaction?

For example, for this [transaction](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5bsTW7HW5jmAq4o3SrsNAXxq72URY2Aw4xJ5mqcDiLPFfHc9bYXPmZN35XcYgAyN6beekVAZcFHqh1G4379Aehep?cluster=devnet) from the devnet, all I can see is the balance of accounts before and after the transaction, but I can't see what actual transfers took place.

Sometimes it's easy to decode instructions, like Token Program: Transfer, where I can see that 0.000012500 SOL is being transferred from 7hkp1x... to Bs7iZq1...

But other times, to understand what's happening in a transaction, it seems like I need to know some implicit rules:

- The fee is paid by the first signer.
- The remaining SOL in a closed account will be returned to the account's owner.
- ...

Are there any more rules I need to know about?

Is there an online or offline tool that can decode a transaction and give me a list of movements between accounts?

I am looking for something like

```
0.000012500 SOL from 7hkp1x... to Bs7iZq1...
```

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "blockTime": 1682290069,
    "meta": {
      "computeUnitsConsumed": 91596,
      "err": null,
      "fee": 5028,
      "innerInstructions": [
        {
          "index": 2,
          "instructions": [
            {
              "parsed": {
                "info": {
                  "amount": "12500",
                  "authority": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
                  "destination": "7hkp1xfPBcD2t1vZMoWWQPzipHVcXeLAAaiGXdPSfDie",
                  "source": "Bs7iZq12cZ8SoAMHEP6RpRfDozahXzK1z93d2ybMf98U"
                },
                "type": "transfer"
              },
              "program": "spl-token",
              "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "logMessages": [
        "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
        "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
        "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
        "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
        "Program SW1TCH7qEPTdLsDHRgPuMQjbQxKdH2aBStViMFnt64f invoke [1]",
        "Program log: Instruction: CrankPop",
        "Program log: Initiating Crank Pop @ 1682290069 = [1682290069, GvDMxPzN1sCj7L26YDK2HnMRXEQmQ2aemov8YBtPS7vR]",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
        "Program log: Instruction: Transfer",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4736 of 120469 compute units",
        "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
        "Program data: 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",
        "Program SW1TCH7qEPTdLsDHRgPuMQjbQxKdH2aBStViMFnt64f consumed 91596 of 200000 compute units",
        "Program SW1TCH7qEPTdLsDHRgPuMQjbQxKdH2aBStViMFnt64f success"
      ],
      "postBalances": [
        1730670979484,
        3480000,
        292673389280,
        37579509283,
        3480000,
        3480000,
        3480000,
        27693840,
        44747965093,
        39571619243,
        27693840,
        4043760,
        3897600,
        279346560,
        42184440118,
        4043760,
        27693840,
        4043760,
        4043760,
        9723120,
        27693840,
        1,
        1001000000,
        223666560,
        747729315002,
        1141440,
        934087680
      ],
      "postTokenBalances": [
        {
          "accountIndex": 2,
          "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "owner": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
          "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "amount": "292671350000",
            "decimals": 9,
            "uiAmount": 292.67135,
            "uiAmountString": "292.67135"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 3,
          "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "owner": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
          "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "amount": "37577470003",
            "decimals": 9,
            "uiAmount": 37.577470003,
            "uiAmountString": "37.577470003"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 8,
          "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "owner": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
          "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "amount": "44745925813",
            "decimals": 9,
            "uiAmount": 44.745925813,
            "uiAmountString": "44.745925813"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 9,
          "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "owner": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
          "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "amount": "39569579963",
            "decimals": 9,
            "uiAmount": 39.569579963,
            "uiAmountString": "39.569579963"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 14,
          "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "owner": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
          "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "amount": "42182400838",
            "decimals": 9,
            "uiAmount": 42.182400838,
            "uiAmountString": "42.182400838"
          }
        }
      ],
      "preBalances": [
        1730670984512,
        3480000,
        292673376780,
        37579509283,
        3480000,
        3480000,
        3480000,
        27693840,
        44747977593,
        39571619243,
        27693840,
        4043760,
        3897600,
        279346560,
        42184440118,
        4043760,
        27693840,
        4043760,
        4043760,
        9723120,
        27693840,
        1,
        1001000000,
        223666560,
        747729315002,
        1141440,
        934087680
      ],
      "preTokenBalances": [
        {
          "accountIndex": 2,
          "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "owner": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
          "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "amount": "292671337500",
            "decimals": 9,
            "uiAmount": 292.6713375,
            "uiAmountString": "292.6713375"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 3,
          "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "owner": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
          "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "amount": "37577470003",
            "decimals": 9,
            "uiAmount": 37.577470003,
            "uiAmountString": "37.577470003"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 8,
          "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "owner": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
          "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "amount": "44745938313",
            "decimals": 9,
            "uiAmount": 44.745938313,
            "uiAmountString": "44.745938313"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 9,
          "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "owner": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
          "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "amount": "39569579963",
            "decimals": 9,
            "uiAmount": 39.569579963,
            "uiAmountString": "39.569579963"
          }
        },
        {
          "accountIndex": 14,
          "mint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
          "owner": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
          "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "uiTokenAmount": {
            "amount": "42182400838",
            "decimals": 9,
            "uiAmount": 42.182400838,
            "uiAmountString": "42.182400838"
          }
        }
      ],
      "rewards": [],
      "status": {
        "Ok": null
      }
    },
    "slot": 211137537,
    "transaction": {
      "message": {
        "accountKeys": [
          {
            "pubkey": "2KgowxogBrGqRcgXQEmqFvC3PGtCu66qERNJevYW8Ajh",
            "signer": true,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "5kSxpX1Tbe5rid219eWVkdPnjCpQXRoHUDueWe8WpPzk",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "7hkp1xfPBcD2t1vZMoWWQPzipHVcXeLAAaiGXdPSfDie",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "7RBSc6NBvpwcF9XXAbrn5WLgx14XGX6fHXChyEgR38Vu",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "8WwgiLmFZP344Xd7SpfGs3c2ZpnLMUH6EQZVyBeowsTm",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "9gu3tri7UbW8cLsFDMQP7mEsYdEh2d4bvijWtmw81YYo",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "B7ZMMzxZ4AYSqxQattFKgPDoVAcYwey4hCSrFzHnkUFh",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "BjUgj6YCnFBZ49wF54ddBVA9qu8TeqkFtkbqmZcee8uW",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "Bs7iZq12cZ8SoAMHEP6RpRfDozahXzK1z93d2ybMf98U",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "BwRNHbPu5cyo5SEoda71HcMFPt8b53fDzdDjcadLbe6s",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "CdvmFaR2m3cL2YuDg9cSb2m3nKZX26vyVoBbB8aNMWaj",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "ChBRNDsRkz8em1fopNaMEZGUuozaNEtcNU9YdKLebbco",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "crnKsPsuP6f7uiDbAYYw66h2RNBrqoazmtZHwazkC6V",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "dBufw5cfPqte3VtsAcbvwA2b3fsCXgck4dsAc7mU51R",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "FdPFrUhiZ8rbxMAiWrWdnxuUwro87oXiLbzjNHVGqjdr",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "Guwy9H6dWLPxUGU1ZTga85vsyLW5LfM4WL2wGvoP3LmT",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "GvDMxPzN1sCj7L26YDK2HnMRXEQmQ2aemov8YBtPS7vR",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "HwWkCcurmxfVjM3WHfBDDeqJRhueN4hqSkrwfAGVDMmP",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "HyPJSJhV1bzkeSoYkJComxwYzseP7LYpsgkabZhhizLz",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "PeRMnAqNqHQYHUuCBEjhm1XPeVTh4BxjY4t4TPan1pG",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "WMW5xc3HypXwTnPesyUT49uLsyHwNURsWAEk39onKuk",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": true
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": false
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": false
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "dBufSqtKN59Whpq3oeh6pyxJm1yzpf9XJTTubTKVQtf",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": false
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": false
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "SW1TCH7qEPTdLsDHRgPuMQjbQxKdH2aBStViMFnt64f",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": false
          },
          {
            "pubkey": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
            "signer": false,
            "source": "transaction",
            "writable": false
          }
        ],
        "addressTableLookups": null,
        "instructions": [
          {
            "accounts": [],
            "data": "3csjmdxWs7vf",
            "programId": "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111"
          },
          {
            "accounts": [],
            "data": "Fj2Eoy",
            "programId": "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111"
          },
          {
            "accounts": [
              "crnKsPsuP6f7uiDbAYYw66h2RNBrqoazmtZHwazkC6V",
              "PeRMnAqNqHQYHUuCBEjhm1XPeVTh4BxjY4t4TPan1pG",
              "2KgowxogBrGqRcgXQEmqFvC3PGtCu66qERNJevYW8Ajh",
              "CyZuD7RPDcrqCGbNvLCyqk6Py9cEZTKmNKujfPi3ynDd",
              "7hkp1xfPBcD2t1vZMoWWQPzipHVcXeLAAaiGXdPSfDie",
              "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
              "dBufw5cfPqte3VtsAcbvwA2b3fsCXgck4dsAc7mU51R",
              "dBufSqtKN59Whpq3oeh6pyxJm1yzpf9XJTTubTKVQtf",
              "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
              "WMW5xc3HypXwTnPesyUT49uLsyHwNURsWAEk39onKuk",
              "5kSxpX1Tbe5rid219eWVkdPnjCpQXRoHUDueWe8WpPzk",
              "7RBSc6NBvpwcF9XXAbrn5WLgx14XGX6fHXChyEgR38Vu",
              "8WwgiLmFZP344Xd7SpfGs3c2ZpnLMUH6EQZVyBeowsTm",
              "9gu3tri7UbW8cLsFDMQP7mEsYdEh2d4bvijWtmw81YYo",
              "B7ZMMzxZ4AYSqxQattFKgPDoVAcYwey4hCSrFzHnkUFh",
              "BjUgj6YCnFBZ49wF54ddBVA9qu8TeqkFtkbqmZcee8uW",
              "Bs7iZq12cZ8SoAMHEP6RpRfDozahXzK1z93d2ybMf98U",
              "BwRNHbPu5cyo5SEoda71HcMFPt8b53fDzdDjcadLbe6s",
              "CdvmFaR2m3cL2YuDg9cSb2m3nKZX26vyVoBbB8aNMWaj",
              "ChBRNDsRkz8em1fopNaMEZGUuozaNEtcNU9YdKLebbco",
              "FdPFrUhiZ8rbxMAiWrWdnxuUwro87oXiLbzjNHVGqjdr",
              "Guwy9H6dWLPxUGU1ZTga85vsyLW5LfM4WL2wGvoP3LmT",
              "GvDMxPzN1sCj7L26YDK2HnMRXEQmQ2aemov8YBtPS7vR",
              "HwWkCcurmxfVjM3WHfBDDeqJRhueN4hqSkrwfAGVDMmP",
              "HyPJSJhV1bzkeSoYkJComxwYzseP7LYpsgkabZhhizLz"
            ],
            "data": "2o2JNCMcp6ZiBGiKfP4HNb9ZNDNjgJm9N5DKmZ4rg6aSJVku78UXNLJJDXuJTqLdbnDTjb6zE5Myr",
            "programId": "SW1TCH7qEPTdLsDHRgPuMQjbQxKdH2aBStViMFnt64f"
          }
        ],
        "recentBlockhash": "3UktfghwEwk4VTBKRbURQ9QGTj4vRTSr3JvSTJSkUHYo"
      },
      "signatures": [
        "5bsTW7HW5jmAq4o3SrsNAXxq72URY2Aw4xJ5mqcDiLPFfHc9bYXPmZN35XcYgAyN6beekVAZcFHqh1G4379Aehep"
      ]
    },
    "version": "legacy"
  },
  "id": "80f845e4-adc8-4049-ae2c-cccfb5339d84"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem before its difficult to figure out.
There is one more case which is when a transfer in a program is done via

```
**ctx
 .accounts
 .chest_vault
 .to_account_info()
 .try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += something;
```

Then you also wouldnt see it as a transfer, but it may be a transfer from a pda to a wallet. You could try https://xray.helius.xyz/ and see if it shows what you want. Here is the api they are using: https://docs.helius.xyz/solana-apis/enhanced-transactions-api/parse-transaction-s